# How To Change Tab bar color in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, colors, tabs, uitabbarcontroller

How do I go about changing the tab bar color in this code? My tab bar is black. On click changes it to blue.  I want to change the tow color to any other color.

This code is from :application.m
and there :rotatingTabBarController.m ,rotatingTabBarController.h

```
//  1B) If this app uses tabs, create a tabbed navigation application and set the default screen for each tab
//      to the defaultScreenGuid in the tabs data
if([self.tabs count] > 0){
    [BT_debugger showIt:self:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"building a tabbed based navigation app%@", @""]];

    if([self.screens count] > 0){

        //appDelegate
        qoqb_appDelegate *appDelegate = (qoqb_appDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];   

        //initialize the tab bar controller
        rootTabBarController = [[BT_rotatingTabBarController alloc] init];
        [rootTabBarController.view setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        [rootTabBarController setDelegate:appDelegate];
        rootTabBarController.view.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);

        //if we have a tabbar color setup in the theme
        if(self.rootTheme != nil){
            if([self.rootTheme.jsonVars objectForKey:@"tabBarColor"]){
                if([[self.rootTheme.jsonVars objectForKey:@"tabBarColor"] length] > 3){
                    UIColor *tabberColor = [BT_color getColorFromHexString:[self.rootTheme.jsonVars objectForKey:@"tabBarColor"]];
                    NSString *tabberOpacity = @".50";
                    if([self.rootTheme.jsonVars objectForKey:@"tabBarColorOpacity"]){
                        if([[self.rootTheme.jsonVars objectForKey:@"tabBarColorOpacity"] length] > 0){
                            tabberOpacity = [NSString stringWithFormat:@".%@", [self.rootTheme.jsonVars objectForKey:@"tabBarColorOpacity"]];
                            if([tabberOpacity isEqualToString:@".100"]) tabberOpacity = @".50";
                        }
                        //colorize the tab-bar
                        [rootTabBarController addTabColor:tabberColor:[tabberOpacity doubleValue]];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //Fill a temporary array of view controllers to assign to tab bar controller
        NSMutableArray *tmpViewControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 

        //loop through each tab bar item in application data
        for(int i = 0; i < [[self tabs] count]; i++){

            //this tab
            BT_item *thisTab = (BT_item *)[[self tabs] objectAtIndex:i];
            NSString *textLabel = [[thisTab jsonVars] objectForKey:@"textLabel"];               
            UIImage *tabIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:[[thisTab jsonVars] objectForKey:@"iconName"]];              

            //get the screen from the apps array of screens for this tab's view controller
            if([[thisTab jsonVars] objectForKey:@"homeScreenItemId"]){

                BT_item *thisTabsDefaultScreenData = [self getScreenDataByItemId:[[thisTab jsonVars] objectForKey:@"homeScreenItemId"]];

                //if this is the first tab in the list, remember it as the "currently loaded screen", also make it the "previously loaded screen"
                if(i == 0){
                    [self setCurrentScreenData:thisTabsDefaultScreenData];
                    [self setPreviousScreenData:thisTabsDefaultScreenData];
                    [thisTabsDefaultScreenData setIsHomeScreen:TRUE];

                    //if theScreen has an audio file..load it in the delegate
                    if([[BT_strings getJsonPropertyValue:thisTabsDefaultScreenData.jsonVars:@"audioFileName":@""] length] > 3){

                        //appDelegate
                        qoqb_appDelegate *appDelegate = (qoqb_appDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];   

                        //initialize audio in different thread to prevent UI blocking
                        [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector: @selector(loadAudioForScreen:) toTarget:appDelegate withObject:thisTabsDefaultScreenData];

                    }                       

                }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
tabBar.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

will crash if your IOS version is not IOS 5 see the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

a safer approach is:

```
if ([tabBarController.tabBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setTintColor:)]) {
    [tabBarController.tabBar setTintColor:color];
}
```

//NEW CODE

```
if ([rootTabBarController.tabBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setTintColor:)]) {
    [rootTabBarController.tabBar setTintColor:tabberColor];
}
```

Comment: i use latest xcode with ios5 simulation... i try to put the code before and after and i get error

Comment: i make screenshot for the error at :http://imageupper.com/s02/1/7/O13353450461627064_1.jpg

Comment: added an update. that should work. You need to remove the line:    //colorize the tab-bar
                            [rootTabBarController addTabColor:tabberColor:[tabberOpacity doubleValue]];

Comment: now i get one error only ..this is the screenshot:http://imageupper.com/s03/1/2/R13353462121628011_1.jpg

Comment: thank you alot ...now there is no error ..but how can i change the color ...it is still black on my ios simulator

Comment: you loaded your color from ::  [BT_color getColorFromHexString:[self.rootTheme.jsonVars objectForKey:@"tabBarColor"]] maybe something goes wrong there. You can always check with setting tabberColor = [UIColor greenColor]; This should make the tabBar green

Comment: thank you alot tompalompa you help me ..i will try it and i hope it's get green :)... do i need to put tabberColor = [UIColor greenColor]; in same place ?

Comment: do i need to remove: BT_color getColorFromHexString:[self.rootTheme.jsonVars objectForKey:@"tabBarColor"] and how i mark your answer as great here do i need to click any thing ?

Comment: You could as it would look cleaner. but you dont need to. Just mark answer as right

Answer (score 1):

In the AppDelegate.m inside at: `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

Using this coding:

```
// use this for highlighted color
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(256/256.0) green:(0/256.0) blue:(0/256.0) alpha:(1.0)]];

// Use this to channge the tint colo of the entere TabBar
[[UITabBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(255/256.0) green:(0/256.0) blue:(0/256.0) alpha:(1.0)]];

// This change only a background color
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(255/256.0) green:(255/256.0) blue:(255/256.0) alpha:1.0]];

// This for change IMG or color tint on back of highlighted button.
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YourIMG.png"]];
```

That's it that's all ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
tabBar.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

Comment: when require change the tab bar color.In Your code i think before this line....`[rootTabBarController addTabColor:tabberColor:[tabberOpacity doubleValue]];`

Comment: What is name of your tab bar controller.?..You have posted very limited code so i can not find where is your mistake.

Comment: i have this file :BT_viewController ,BT_rotatingNavController,BT_rotatingTabBarController,BT_viewControllerManager. ,BT_viewUtilities. ,BT_application

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor=[UIColor redColor];
return YES;

}
```

> In AppDelegate.m

Answer (score 0):

In IOS7 this is done differently:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

You can follow these steps:

I created a new `UINavigationController` for example `UIDemoNavController` resulting in:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];  
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

This is the full demo class:

```
#import "UIDemoNavController.h"

@interface UIDemoNavController()

@end

@implementation UIDemoNavController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {}
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```